# How to extract multiple values from an array into different rows in KQL?

Tags: arrays, json, azure-data-explorer, kql

Good day,

Suppose I have the following data, which tracks the inside and outside temperatures at a certain location. To save on size, it only measures the temperatures every 15 minutes, and then sends all values after an hour.

```
datatable(T:dynamic)
[
    dynamic
    (
        {
            "name": "Temperature",
            "startTimestamp": "2022-12-14T08:00:00.0000000Z",
            "signals": [
                {
                    "name": "Temperature_inside",
                    "values": [
                        "17.1",
                        "17.5",
                        "17.8",
                        "17.9"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Temperature_outside",
                                "values": [
                        "1.3",
                        "1.4",
                        "1.4",
                        "1.5"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    )
]
```

I've already extended the `startTimestamp` to a number with
`| extend DateTimeKey = format_datetime(creationTimestamp, 'yyyyMMddhhmmss')`, and I'm currently able to take individual values using:

```
T
| mv-apply signal = T.signals on
    (
    summarize make_bag(bag_pack(tostring(signal.name), signal.values[0]))
    ) 
| project-away T
| evaluate bag_unpack(bag_)
```

to get:

| DateTimeKey | Temperature_inside | Temperature_outside |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20221214080000 | 17.1 | 1.3 |

, but I would like to get all values in one go, without having to run the query 4 times for every hour.

Now I know there's a `range` function in Kusto, but I can't get it to work like it would in something like Python. Is there a way to loop over `... , signal.values[i]))`? While at the same time updating the `DateTimeKey` to it's correct value with something like `| extend DateTimeKey = DateTimeKey + (1500 * i)`?

Ideally, the end result would look like:

| DateTimeKey | Temperature_inside | Temperature_outside |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20221214080000 | 17.1 | 1.3 |
| 20221214081500 | 17.5 | 1.4 |
| 20221214083000 | 17.8 | 1.4 |
| 20221214084500 | 17.9 | 1.5 |

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why the temperature values are strings and not numeric?  Why is *signals* array and not a dictionary? Why do you provide a sample data where the column name is the same as the table name?

Comment: Yeah in hindsight not the smartest, but I couldn't find what I wanted to know anywhere, so I just made up a quick example with some copy-pasting without thinking much about the datatypes and such...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
datatable(T:dynamic)
[
    dynamic
    (
        {
            "name": "Temperature",
            "startTimestamp": "2022-12-14T08:00:00.0000000Z",
            "signals": [
                {
                    "name": "Temperature_inside",
                    "values": [
                        "17.1",
                        "17.5",
                        "17.8",
                        "17.9"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Temperature_outside",
                                "values": [
                        "1.3",
                        "1.4",
                        "1.4",
                        "1.5"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    )
]
| mv-expand with_itemindex=i    Temperature_inside  = T.signals[0].values to typeof(decimal)
                               ,Temperature_outside = T.signals[1].values to typeof(decimal) 
| project DateTimeKey = format_datetime(todatetime(T.startTimestamp) + i * 15m, 'yyyyMMddhhmmss')
         ,Temperature_inside
         ,Temperature_outside
```

| DateTimeKey | Temperature_inside | Temperature_outside |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20221214080000 | 17.1 | 1.3 |
| 20221214081500 | 17.5 | 1.4 |
| 20221214083000 | 17.8 | 1.4 |
| 20221214084500 | 17.9 | 1.5 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA6VTwW6CQBC9m/gPEy5iiwSsptbEW2+NN041xmzZsW7DAoHRStr+e4dAVQpiTYdNGGbePGbfzkpB/LwEaHpTmYVCK7/f7Sy6HWArA8WHWbxy+zi6uRmMQmMKhoc6xkTQNkHD+oVJSSTkKY3s6DhHD53hcODyGnnOZOo4vGynsOd6uXoNRZBy3aKaaeinra+VClMla+0dSnYi2OKZ3xxA7r3tnmP4AYwvASaXAA9Gc35ZD381UF0jSrSlNlUq9X9TyL5r3549+md+fIU61dAJoszwxHPwE/RugPtYhBLeFW1WilCrUOJ+pnJUfYoAZuDZ5WgunKVdaAMUAWUxRmtToq+0CPoXdbUajqPC7rawQ958nERv6BM8CsL8nj1hxgTrKNGCVpKDxEGTooPL3JU72YdbUHAD7lhb0MvY5nMpNxut07R3ugOrrsS5bLmTbxAo1F5mBAAA)